# how to make multiple list input through form beside using map method in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There is website in which that website is taking single list entry at a time with bill image for reimbursement my task is to change that single entry to multiple entry without using map method in React JS

I used only method to solve that problem but i need another method.

Comment: @David you are absolutely right but i been assigned a task to do it using different method.

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: nope my manger just want too mess around with me that's why. He says it's for better you.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

> without using map method

I guess without going into any details about *why* you can't use `.map()`, what you *could* do is just write your own alternative to `.map()` and use that.  For example:

```js
Array.prototype.notMap = function(callback) {
  const result = [];
  this.forEach(x => result.push(callback(x)));
  return result;
};

const sourceArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      {sourceArray.notMap(x => <p key={x}>{x}</p>)}
    </div>
  )
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(<App />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Or if you don't want to add to the `Array` prototype and just use a helper function:

```js
const notMap = (arr, callback) => {
  const result = [];
  arr.forEach(x => result.push(callback(x)));
  return result;
};

const sourceArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      {notMap(sourceArray, x => <p key={x}>{x}</p>)}
    </div>
  )
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(<App />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have to check with API integration whether it works for it or not. earlier as I told it was taking a single list element at a time and now it needs multiple bills to be entered.

Comment: @Adarsh: Iterating over an array to produce a new array (which is all `.map()` does) has exactly nothing to do with API integration, nor does the question ask about any problems with integrating with any API.